# replace a system command shutdown with sometghing else

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, system, shutdown

What i have done is renamed the orignal shutdown command /sbin/shutdown to /sbin/shutdown.orignal and then created /sbin/shutdown which contains

```
    echo "yes this was executed" >> /var/www/html/shutdown-logs/temp.txt

    /sbin/shutdown.orignal -h now
```

so that which ever script calls will first have to call shutdown which will then call shutdown.orignal

whenever i try calling shutdown it says permission denied !

How can i solve this

Comment: i am running it as root user !

Comment: give execution permission of script + shutdown.original to all users

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
  echo "yes this was executed" >> /var/www/html/shutdown-logs/temp.txt

   sudo /sbin/shutdown.orignal -h now
```

and

```
sudo chmod 755 /sbin/shutdown
```